# How to create an bash alias for the command "cd ~1"

Tags: bash, pushd

In BASH, I use "pushd . " command to save the current directory on the stack.
After issuing this command in couple of different directories, I have multiple directories saved on the stack which I am able to see by issuing command "dirs".
For example, the output of "dirs" command in my current bash session is given below -

0  ~/eclipse/src
 1  ~/eclipse
 2  ~/parboil/src

Now, to switch to 0th directory, I issue a command "cd ~0".
I want to create a bash alias command or a function for this command.
Something like "xya 0", which will switch to 0th directory on stack.
I wrote following function to achieve this -

xya(){
     cd ~$1
}

Where "$1" in above function, is the first argument passed to the function "xya".

But, I am getting the following error -

**-bash: cd: ~1: No such file or directory**

Can you please tell what is going wrong here ?

Comment: An *alias* wouldn't have this problem, because they happen earlier at evaluation time than functions do. Several expansion phases are already finished before `$1` is replaced with anything.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can you please give an alias command for above problem which can accept arguments ? I tried with this alias command - alias xya='cd ~' followed by argument "1" but this results in switching to the home directory, instead of 1st directory on the stack

Comment: Honestly, aliases are awful, and I'd recommend using a function with `eval` instead. It's a different kind of awful, but at least one that gives you control.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can you give an example on how to use ``` eval ``` in above problem ?

Comment: I did better than that, I *wrote a whole answer* that demonstrates it. If it doesn't display below, perhaps reload the page?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, sorry got it after reloading :)

Comment: What is your goal in defining such an alias? A single-letter name will only save you two keystrokes; `xya 0` doesn't save you *any* compared to `cd ~0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, bash parsing happens in the following order:

- brace expansion
- tilde expansion
- parameter, variable, arithmetic expansion; command substitution (same phase, left-to-right)
- word splitting
- pathname expansion

Thus, by the time your parameter is expanded, tilde expansion is already finished and will not take place again, without doing something explicit like use of `eval`.

---

If you [know the risks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) and are willing to accept them, use `eval` to force parsing to restart at the beginning after the expansion of `$1` is complete. The below tries to mitigate the damage should something that isn't `eval`-safe is passed as an argument:

```
xya() {
  local cmd
  printf -v cmd 'cd ~%q' "$1"
  eval "$cmd"
}
```

...or, less cautiously (which is to say that the below trusts your arguments to be `eval`-safe):

```
xya() {
  eval "cd ~$1"
}
```

Comment: I think `eval "\\builtin cd ~$((0+$1))"` is eval safe and also avoids problems when `cd` is an alias or function.

Comment: I agree; if restricting the input domain to numbers, that's safe. (The existing answer can also work with other inputs, like usernames, or be passed `1/foo` to change to the subdirectory `foo` under the directory name that results from expanding `~1`).

Comment: I don't see a reason to use `builtin` when our function doesn't itself go by the name `cd`; if the user has something overriding `cd`, wouldn't they want its logic to also apply when running `xya` to change directories?

Comment: I alias `cd` to a small function wrapping `pushd`. I don't know how many other people do. When used in conjunction with the alias `xya` I think it's more intuitive to replace the top of the directory stack rather than potentially add a new entry to it and change the indices of the entries in the directory stack.

Comment: Gotcha. Whereas when I see `cd` wrapped, it's more frequently been to do things like check if we changed into a git repository and if so look up some metadata; if that was silently ignored, prompt data depending on it, or such, could be lost. Suppose the best course of action depends on the individual user's setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can let `dirs` print the absolute path for you:

```
xya(){
    cd "$(dirs -${1-0} -l)"
}
```