# Order of events in Bash shell redirection of standard output and error to the same file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, io-redirection

I want to ask a question about redirecting standard output and error to the same file using a Bash Shell.

I am a beginner in the Linux Command Prompt and am reading a book titled "The Linux Command Line" by William E. Shotts. Jr.

In a section on redirection, he states that to redirect standard output and error to the same file, the following command is written:

```
ls -l /bin/usr > ls-output.txt 2>&1
```

From what I understand, the `/bin/usr` directory does not exist, so an error is thrown up and is sent to the standard error file. The output of the command `ls -l /bin/usr` is redirected to a text file `ls-output.txt` and the standard error is redirected to standard output with `2>&1`.

I'm confused here on two aspects:

1. Firstly, the order of events. By my intuition, since I thought commands are executed in an L-R fashion (Left-to-Right), it appears that the redirection of the `ls` command takes place first towards `ls-output.txt` before the redirection of the standard error stream (`2`) to the standard output stream (`1`).
2. The use of the `ampersand`. I understand from a Google search that if `&` is placed at the end of a command, it means that other commands can be input before the initial command is executed - which has application when the initial command is coupled with a timer. I believe that the ampersand here implies that the `&` means that we are redirecting to a file *descriptor* and not a file name named `1`, although I'm unsure whether this is correct.

Overall, I have two questions:

1. What is the order of execution of the command above?
2. Am I correct in the function of the ampersand `&`? If not, what function does it serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux has three default data streams - `stdin (0)`, `stdout (1)` and `stderr (2)`.

- `stdin`, or "standard in", is used for reading data from the user.
- `stdout`, or "standard out", is used for "usual" output.
- `stderr`, or "standard error" is used for errors.

The character `>` allows you to redirect your command's output into one of the streams mentioned above, or in to a file.

When you run the command `ls -l /bin/usr > ls-output.txt 2>&1`, you actually ask from your system two things:

1. Redirect the `stdout` of the command into the file `ls-output.txt`.
2. Redirect the `stderr` of the command into the data stream whose number is 1, which is the `stdout` stream.

Actually, using `>` by itself is equivalent to `1>`, meaning that you redirect all output from data stream no. 1.

The `&` char tells your system that you are going to redirect the output into a data stream, instead of a file. Omitting this character will result in your `stderr` written to a file named `1`.

It is important to note that the character `&` has more roles in Linux, like running commands in the background or concatenating commands (using `&&`), but it is completely different.

Best regards.

Comment: I had a reflection - the redirection happens right when the command has been read fully first i.e. after the redirection of the standard stream? so after `2>&1` will the command actually be executed?

Comment: It is bit more complicated than that. What redirection actually does is replacing the process' file descriptors with those specified by the command. For example, if I have a program which continuously writes "Hello, World" to `stdout`, redirecting its output to a file using `>` will cause the program to write to the file instead to the screen. The program will still run forever, but with its output written to a file. So, for your question - redirection doesn't affect the execution order of a binary, it just changes its file descriptors. Note though that piping are completely different thing.

Comment: many thanks! I'll give you an upvote and a tick for a great explanation! And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to ask more questions if you have :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me expand on aspect 1, the order of events. It's a mistake to think of things happening in strict left-to-right order; command processing and execution happens in *phases* and while each phase is (generally) done left-to-right, each phase will (again, generally) be finished before the next one starts.

In this case, the relevant phases are:

1. The shell parses the command line (this is actually [several phases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58475460/how-to-create-an-bash-alias-for-the-command-cd-1/58475533#58475533) itself).
2. The shell processes I/O redirections (from left to right).
3. The shell executes the command (with all redirects already in place).

One important consequence of this is that you [can't redirect output back to a file you're using as input for the command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/how-can-i-use-a-file-in-a-command-and-redirect-output-to-the-same-file-without-t). For example, if you tried to sort a file with `sort file.txt >file.txt`, the shell would open `file.txt` *and empty it to get it ready for its new contents* before `sort` has a chance to read from it. Result: an empty file.

A less important consequence is that if there's an error in a redirect, it'll prevent the command from even being started. If you run `nosuchcommand <nosuchfile`, bash will print an error about `nosuchfile` not existing before it even notices that `nosuchcommand` doesn't exist either.